# Java Spring web application

Tags: java, spring

Here is a Java Spring web application built as an educational project that fetches and displays data returned from NASA's Mars Weather Service API. The project is essentially an attempt to reverse engineer this page: https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/weather/.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/jkey774/mars-insight-weather

Example API payload: https://github.com/jkey774/mars-insight-weather/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springboot/app/InsightWeather/ExampleJSON.json.

Live demo: https://mars-insight-weather.herokuapp.com/

Note the app is running on a free dyno so it can be slow to load if the application goes to sleep from being unused for some period of time and is not related to code quality.

1) Have I built the application in a way that is acceptable within the Spring framework? Am I making proper use of Dependency Injection? Do you see any anti-patterns?

2) Should I have implemented Interfaces with the different classes (i.e. Sol, AirTemperature, AirPressure, WindSpeed, WindDirection) https://github.com/jkey774/mars-insight-weather/tree/master/src/main/java/com/springboot/app/InsightWeather

3) Does the project seem scalable and extensible? If not, how could I make it more so? Here is the Controller class and primary Component class

```
@Controller
public class SolsController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sols(@RequestParam(name="sols", required=false, defaultValue="") String name, Model model) throws IOException {

        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
        RestService restService = new RestService(restTemplateBuilder);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(restService.getSols());

        JsonNode solKeyNodes = rootNode.get("sol_keys");
        Iterator<JsonNode> solKeys = solKeyNodes.elements();

        ArrayNode solsData = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
        ObjectNode lastSolNode = null;

        int i = 0;
        while (solKeys.hasNext()) {
            String solKey = solKeys.next().asText();
            ObjectNode sol = objectMapper.convertValue(rootNode.path(solKey), ObjectNode.class);
            sol.put("id", solKey);
            solsData.add(sol);
            if (i == solKeyNodes.size() - 1) {
                lastSolNode = sol;
            }
            i++;
        }

        Sol mostRecentSol = objectMapper.convertValue(lastSolNode, Sol.class);
        model.addAttribute("mostRecentSol", mostRecentSol);

        Sol[] sols = objectMapper.convertValue(solsData, Sol[].class);
        model.addAttribute("solsCalendar", sols);
        model.addAttribute("solsTable", reverseSols(sols, sols.length));

        return "sols";
    }

    private static Sol[] reverseSols(Sol[] original, int length) {
        Sol[] reversed = new Sol[length];

        int j = length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            reversed[j - 1] = original[i];
            j -= 1;
        }

        return reversed;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Component
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Sol implements Serializable {

    private String id;

    private String earthDateTimestamp;
    private EarthDate earthDate;

    private ObjectNode airTemperatureData;
    private AirTemperature airTemperature;

    private ObjectNode airPressureData;
    private AirPressure airPressure;

    private ObjectNode windSpeedData;
    private WindSpeed windSpeed;

    private ObjectNode windDirectionData;
    private WindDirection windDirection;

    public Sol() {}

    @JsonCreator
    public Sol(
            @JsonProperty("id") String id,
            @JsonProperty("First_UTC") String earthDateTimestamp,
            @JsonProperty("AT") ObjectNode airTemperatureData,
            @JsonProperty("PRE") ObjectNode airPressureData,
            @JsonProperty("HWS") ObjectNode windSpeedData,
            @JsonProperty("WD") ObjectNode windDirectionData
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.earthDateTimestamp = earthDateTimestamp;
        this.airTemperatureData = airTemperatureData;
        this.airPressureData = airPressureData;
        this.windSpeedData = windSpeedData;
        this.windDirectionData = windDirectionData;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EarthDate getEarthDate() {
        return new EarthDate(this.earthDateTimestamp);
    }

    public void setEarthDate() {
        this.earthDate = new EarthDate(this.earthDateTimestamp);
    }

    public AirTemperature getAirTemperature() {
        return new AirTemperature(this.airTemperatureData);
    }

    public void setAirTemperature() {
        this.airTemperature = new AirTemperature(this.airTemperatureData);
    }

    public AirPressure getAirPressure() { 
       enter code herereturn new AirPressure(this.airPressureData); 
    }

    public void setAirPressure() {
        this.airPressure = new AirPressure(this.airPressureData);
    }

    public WindSpeed getWindSpeed() {
        return new WindSpeed(this.windSpeedData);
    }

    public void setWindSpeed() {
        this.windSpeed = new WindSpeed(this.windSpeedData);
    }

    public WindDirection getWindDirection() {
        return new WindDirection(this.windDirectionData);
    }

    public void setWindDirection() {
        this.windDirection = new WindDirection(this.windDirectionData);
    }

}
```

4) In src/main/java/com/springboot/app/InsightWeather/Sol.java this class implements Serializable. This worked well with Thymeleaf's 'for each' templating, but could implementing Serializable be frowned upon?

```
public class Sol implements Serializable
```

...

```
<div class="item" th:each="sol : ${solsCalendar}">
  <span class="dateSol" th:text="${'Sol ' + sol.id}"></span>
```

5) "I don't know what I don't know." Is there anything else not listed above that you feel is worth mentioning in terms of performance, security, or overall setup?